# minlength and items are not working in typeahead in Bootstrap and how to add scrollbar for suggestions.

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I have added items and minlength in typeahead but its not working, only the default settings are working, below is the code for the reference. what is the solution and how do I add the scrollbar if the suggestions are more than 5. please help.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            processData(data);
         }   

     });

    function processData(data) {
         var myData = JSON.parse(data);
         var Names = [];
         for (var i = 0; i<myData.length; i++) {
            Names.push(myData[i].name);
         }

        $("#typeahead").typeahead({
            source: Names});

        $("#typeahead").typeahead({
            items : 5,
            minLength : 3
        });

        $("#typeahead").typeahead({
            matcher: function (item) {
                if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                return true;
               }
            }
        });

        $("#typeahead").typeahead({
            sorter: function(items){
                return items.sort(); 

            }
        });  

        $("#typeahead").typeahead({  
                updater: function(item){
                selectedName = myData[item].name;
                return item;
           }
        });
        $("#typeahead").typeahead({  
            highlighter: function(item){
                var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
                return item.replace( regex, "<strong>$1</strong>" );
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You initiated the same typeahead multiple times, I guess only the last options you set would affect the element. I altered the code to combine all in one `.typeahead()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        processData(data);
        console.log('Hi there'); // Check if this is printed in console to verify the request ended with success
     }   

 });

    function processData(data) {
         var myData = JSON.parse(data);
         var Names = [];
         for (var i = 0; i<myData.length; i++) {
            Names.push(myData[i].name);
         }

        $("#typeahead").typeahead({
            source: Names,
            items : 5, // This will always limit the results to 5, scrolling will not load more items.
            minLength : 3,
            matcher: function (item) {
                if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                   return true;
               }
            },
            sorter: function(items) {
                return items.sort(); 
            },  
            updater: function(item){
                selectedName = myData[item].name;
                return item;
           }, 
           highlighter: function(item) {
                var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
                return item.replace( regex, "<strong>$1</strong>" );
           }
        });
    }
```

For the scrolling you'll need some custom CSS:

```
.tt-menu {
    max-height: 300px; // set any hight
    overflow-y: auto; // auto or scroll, with scroll a scrollbar will be visible even if the max-height was not reached
}
```